# Partition BY start time of day in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, partition-by

Looking for ways to specify the start time of a PARTITION BY statement in SQL Server.

Partitioning a years worth of data into 60 minute segments.  The data is 10 minute collections from an IOT device.
Would like the partitions to start at 6AM each day.

How do I accomplish that fixed start time every day?

Here's some sample data.  Want the windowing (partition) to start on the hour:

Sample data, 10 minute data sampling:

| code | datetimePDT | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA01 | 12/15/2021 05:44 AM | 0100 |
| AA02 | 12/15/2021 05:54 AM | 0105 |
| AA03 | 12/15/2021 06:04 AM | 0103 |
| AA04 | 12/15/2021 06:14 AM | 0109 |
| AA05 | 12/15/2021 06:24 AM | 0112 |
| AA06 | 12/15/2021 06:34 AM | 0115 |
| AA07 | 12/15/2021 06:44 AM | 0119 |
| AA08 | 12/15/2021 06:54 AM | 0125 |
| AA09 | 12/15/2021 07:04 AM | 0135 |
| AA10 | 12/15/2021 07:14 AM | 0155 |
| AA11 | 12/15/2021 07:24 AM | 0195 |

In a stored procedure -
Ranking by minute:
dense_rank() over (order by datepart(day,datetimePDT), datepart(hour,datetimePDT), datepart(minute,datetimePDT)) minuteRank

Grouping minutes into hours:
CEILING((minuteRank-1)/10) hourGroup

Then doing things like pulling out the average:
avg(data) over (partition by hourGroup) as GroupAVG

Prefer the hourGroup to start at 6 AM, so my GroupAVG is over the rows from 6:04 to 6:54, and the next partition is from 7-8 AM.

To make this more complicated, there may be missing data, so I can't rely on the data collection period being 10 minutes.

Want to get here:

| code | datetimePDT | data | minuteRank | hourGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA01 | 12/15/2021 05:44 AM | 0100 | 01 | NULL |
| AA02 | 12/15/2021 05:54 AM | 0105 | 02 | NULL |
| AA03 | 12/15/2021 06:04 AM | 0103 | 03 | 0001 |
| AA04 | 12/15/2021 06:14 AM | 0109 | 04 | 0001 |
| AA05 | 12/15/2021 06:24 AM | 0112 | 05 | 0001 |
| AA06 | 12/15/2021 06:34 AM | 0115 | 06 | 0001 |
| AA07 | 12/15/2021 06:44 AM | 0119 | 07 | 0001 |
| AA08 | 12/15/2021 06:54 AM | 0125 | 08 | 0001 |
| AA09 | 12/15/2021 07:04 AM | 0135 | 09 | 0002 |
| AA10 | 12/15/2021 07:14 AM | 0155 | 10 | 0002 |
| AA11 | 12/15/2021 07:24 AM | 0195 | 11 | 0002 |

Comment: So what about the data before `09:00`? You aren't very clearly here. Some sample data, expected results, *and* **your attempts** will help us help you.

Comment: Ignoring the 9AM problem mentioned, you would need to partition by DATE and hour, correct? DATEPART will get the hour from a datetime (or similar) datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
Declare @testTable table (MyTestDate datetime);
 Insert Into @testTable (MyTestDate)
 Values ('2022-02-12 04:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 05:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 06:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 07:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 08:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 09:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 10:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 11:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 12:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 13:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 14:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 15:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 16:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 17:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 18:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 19:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 20:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-12 12:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 04:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 05:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 06:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 07:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 08:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 09:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 10:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 11:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 12:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 13:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 14:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 15:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 16:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 17:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 18:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 19:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 20:06:57.683')
      , ('2022-02-13 12:06:57.683');

Select *
     , row_number() Over(Partition By t.start_date Order By tt.MyTestDate)
  From @testTable tt
 Cross Apply (Values(dateadd(day, datediff(day, '09:00', tt.MyTestDate) - iif(datepart(hour, tt.MyTestDate) < 9, 1, 0), '09:00'))) As t(start_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the reasoning for `PARTITION BY` instead of just `GROUP BY` on the `HOUR`? You could play around with it obviously and put the aggregation into a CTE if you still want to see the individual values.

EDIT: Added a CTE and `CASE` expression in final select to partition as noted by Jeff.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (code VARCHAR(10), datetimePDT DATETIME, [data] INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('AA01','12/15/2021 05:44 AM', 0100),
('AA02','12/15/2021 05:54 AM', 0105),
('AA03','12/15/2021 06:04 AM', 0103),
('AA04','12/15/2021 06:14 AM', 0109),
('AA05','12/15/2021 06:24 AM', 0112),
('AA06','12/15/2021 06:34 AM', 0115),
('AA07','12/15/2021 06:44 AM', 0119),
('AA08','12/15/2021 06:54 AM', 0125),
('AA09','12/15/2021 07:04 AM', 0135),
('AA10','12/15/2021 07:14 AM', 0155),
('AA11','12/15/2021 07:24 AM', 0195);

WITH DataAgg
AS
(
SELECT MIN(tt.code) AS FirstOfGroup,
    MAX(tt.code) AS LastOfGroup,
    COUNT(tt.code) AS NumberInGroup,
    DATEPART(YEAR,tt.datetimePDT) AS [DataYear],
    DATEPART(MONTH,tt.datetimePDT) AS [DataMonth],
    DATEPART(DAY,tt.datetimePDT) AS [DataDay],
    DATEPART(HOUR,tt.datetimePDT) AS [DataHour],
    AVG(tt.[data]) AS AvgData
FROM @Table tt
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,tt.datetimePDT),DATEPART(MONTH,tt.datetimePDT),DATEPART(DAY,tt.datetimePDT), DATEPART(HOUR,tt.datetimePDT)
)

SELECT t.code,
    t.datetimePDT,
    t.data,
    d.AvgData AS 'HourAvg', 
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.datetimePDT) >= 6 THEN CAST(t.datetimePDT AS DATE)
         WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.datetimePDT) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,t.datetimePDT) AS DATE) END AS 'DataDate'
FROM @Table t
    LEFT JOIN DataAgg d ON t.code BETWEEN d.FirstOfGroup AND d.LastOfGroup
```

| FirstOfGroup | LastOfGroup | NumberInGroup | DataYear | DataMonth | DataDay | DataHour | AvgData |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA01 | AA02 | 2 | 2021 | 12 | 15 | 5 | 102 |
| AA03 | AA08 | 6 | 2021 | 12 | 15 | 6 | 113 |
| AA09 | AA11 | 3 | 2021 | 12 | 15 | 7 | 161 |

| code | datetimePDT | data | HourAvg | DataDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA01 | 2021-12-15 05:44:00.000 | 100 | 102 | 2021-12-14 |
| AA02 | 2021-12-15 05:54:00.000 | 105 | 102 | 2021-12-14 |
| AA03 | 2021-12-15 06:04:00.000 | 103 | 113 | 2021-12-15 |
| AA04 | 2021-12-15 06:14:00.000 | 109 | 113 | 2021-12-15 |
| AA05 | 2021-12-15 06:24:00.000 | 112 | 113 | 2021-12-15 |
| AA06 | 2021-12-15 06:34:00.000 | 115 | 113 | 2021-12-15 |
| AA07 | 2021-12-15 06:44:00.000 | 119 | 113 | 2021-12-15 |
| AA08 | 2021-12-15 06:54:00.000 | 125 | 113 | 2021-12-15 |
| AA09 | 2021-12-15 07:04:00.000 | 135 | 161 | 2021-12-15 |
| AA10 | 2021-12-15 07:14:00.000 | 155 | 161 | 2021-12-15 |
| AA11 | 2021-12-15 07:24:00.000 | 195 | 161 | 2021-12-15 |

Comment: Good idea.  Thanks for pointing out the forest through the trees!

Comment: If the 'day' is defined as 9am to 9am - then grouping by date/hour will not be enough.  You still need to identify the partition at the date level for each group, then you can calculate the first, second,... hour groups per date group and minute groups (looks like every 10 minutes).  If the cutoff time is 9am - then anything in the 8am time would be hour group 24 for the previous day and not group 8 for the current day.